# Read pattern from file and write to another file using python

Tags: python, file

i wish to read each function from the file, write it to a new file which is separate for each function.

input_file as:

```
function Script1(){
  var player = GetPlayer();
}    
function Script2(){
  var sVar1 = 3;    
}    
function Script3(){
  var sVar1 = 2;    
}
```

how do I copy the contents of each function?

Comment: input file is js. i am using python to read/write files.

Comment: So you want each variable in each function put into its own text file? Or do you want the function declaration and braces as well?

Comment: yes, function declaration and bra.ces as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression, assuming all functions start on their own line (`function SomeName()\n`) and end on a new line (`\n}`), as in your example:

```
import re

with open('file.js', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

functions = re.findall(r'(function\s.+?\(.*?\)\n.+?\n\})', content, re.DOTALL)
for i, func in enumerate(functions):
    with open('func{}.js'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write(func)
```

*Remember `re.DOTALL` to make your regular expression match functions spanning over multiple lines.*

**Output example:**

func1.js:

```
function Script1(){
  var player = GetPlayer();
}
```

Comment: This should do it, but creating new file for each function gives a type error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.

with open('func' + i + '.js', 'w') as f:

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected it. The js confused my python for a second. You can use `'func{}.js'.format(i)` as the new filenames

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regular expressions:

```
import re

with open('input_file.js', 'r') as file:
    script_str = file.read()

exp = re.compile(r'function\s+([^\s(]+)\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{([^}]*)\}')
matches = exp.findall(script_str)
for m in matches:
    script_name, script_content = m[0], m[1].strip()
    with open('%s.js' % script_name, 'w') as file:
        file.write(script_content)
```

If you want to capture functions arguments too just add a group in the corresponding part of the regular expression (i.e. surround `[^)]*` with parentheses).

Comment: feels right, it gives a type error as '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not iterable(for m in matches)
also, does this create a new file for each function read.

Comment: @Dev-One Sorry, it was `exp.findall`, not `exp.match`. This does not create any file, only a dict object in memory. You may want to write it to a file, or print it or whatever.

Comment: Ohh, ok, I didn't understand that part, I'll fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript source code is simple and nicely formatted to begin with, you might get by using regex.

For anything more involved, I would suggest a proper parser like [pynarcissus](https://code.google.com/p/pynarcissus/).